# C# Reading .wav RIFF byte data from POST response

Tags: c#, arrays, wav

I'm sending a POST request with a press of a button and what I'm getting back is an error telling me:

`No MediaTypeFOrmatter is available to read an object of type 'Byte[]' from content with media type 'audio/wav'.`

When sending the request, fiddler shows me a positive reply and I can play the audio in the WebView  tab with no problem.

What I want is to properly store all bytes into an array that I can leter use to write a .wav file.

What can be done here?

Code:

```csharp
var handler = new HttpClientHandler();

            // If you are using .NET Core 3.0+ you can replace `~DecompressionMethods.None` to `DecompressionMethods.All`
            handler.AutomaticDecompression = ~DecompressionMethods.None;

            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient(handler))
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod("POST"), URL))
                {

                    string uri = URL;
                    request.Content = new StringContent("{\"audio_file\":\"dog\",\"doc\":\"" + Input.Text + "\"}");
                    request.Content.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("application/json");


                    //send
                    var send = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);


                    HttpResponseMessage result = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.OK);
// Error is here
                    result.Content = new ByteArrayContent(send.Content.ReadAsAsync<byte[]> ().Result);  // <----- Error is here
                    result.Content.Headers.ContentType =
                        new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream");

                    //File.WriteAllBytes("output.wav", bytes);
                }
            }
```

Comment: Delete everything _after_ `var send = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);` and replace it with : `File.WriteAllBytes("output.wav", await send.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync());`

Comment: Oh my goodness, I thought the solution was more complex. Thank you very much!

Comment: There are more memory-efficient ways to do this. For example, it'd be better to use `await send.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync()`, then copy the stream to a file. But either will work.